# Is there any conflict script with Bootstrap 4 Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, datepicker

I want to do a simple bootstrap datepicker a pretty big page but I can't get it work despite all the scripts and stylesheets.

Here is the code :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
$(function() {
  'use strict'
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(function () {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
      });
    });
  });
})
</script>
```

I mean I don't have the modal but an ugly buggy calendar next to the input section.
Here is 2 picture showing what I have and what I'm looking(basic BS Datepicker example)

bad result

[image: bad result]

normal result

[image: normal result]

No error in console and can't find the same problem anywhere on the net.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/theoH/svp75k1f/16/) showing the exact problem I have with all the scripts I have.

Maybe I'm not looking at the right thing but I've been looking quite a time at script loading but can't figure out where the problem is...

Comment: The calendar works, though.  So what's the problem?  That it's ugly?

Comment: Have you added any possibly required CSS too?

Comment: I think so, I've not face any issues with pure BS4 and you only theoricaly need the script and css "bootstrap-datepicker" to get datepicker to work.

Comment: I dont think that your datepicker is compatible with bootstrap v4

Comment: Probably need to be more specific - there are quite a few Bootstrap Datepicker plugins, not all of which are compatible with Bootstrap 4. The version in your fiddle is one of those that has not been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than a few issues with the linked jsFiddle, which, if it matches your local setup, is likely the problem.

Basically:

1. You've linked the jQuery UI library - that has known conflicts with Bootstrap, especially Bootstrap 3 and lower.
2. Some of your scripts are out of order - popper.js must be loaded before bootstrap.js
3. Bootstrap 4 changed how input groups are classed and what elements should be used. Probably want to review the updated docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/input-group/
4. You have three different ondomready event handlers - just need one.
5. You need to use the *bootstrap-datepicker3.css* or *bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css* file - the "unnumbered" version is for Bootstrap 2, which definitely won't work.

This works: https://jsfiddle.net/z1x7f8p4/. Here's the code from the updated fiddle:

**HTML**

```html
<div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" />
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, all your answer has been useful. My main problem was the datepicker3 instead of datepicker and the jQueryUI issue

Answer (score -2):

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="birthday">
<script>
$(function() {
  $('input[name="birthday"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    minYear: 1901,
    maxYear: parseInt(moment().format('YYYY'),10)
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    var years = moment().diff(start, 'years');
    alert("You are " + years + " years old!");
  });
});
</script>
```

To find more examples and the **css** and **js** files take a look at https://www.daterangepicker.com/